# How much time I need to spend on visiting Border Abbeys, south from Edinburgh?

Tags: planning, itineraries, scotland

I want to do an extensive car trip through Scotland next year in June and I started to gather information and plan it in time.

Particularly, one of the areas I am looking at is south from Edinburgh. I've read a book and listed such places:

- Rosslyn Chapel
- Melrose Abbey
- Scott’s View
- Dryburgh Abbey
- Mellerstain House
- Dawyck Garden
- Kailzie Garden

Out of first 4, which ones would you suggest as worth visiting? How much different are they from one another (abbeys, gardens)? How much time would I need to visit them (excluding transit)?

Preferrably, we'd want to spend 1 full day in the area, so we need to pick best spots out of the list. What would you suggest?

Assumptions:

- we have a car
- we are not afraid of walking all day long

Comment: I also ask for suggestions for choice

Comment: I don't undestand the problem actually, I will have an informed opinion after I travel, but now I'm trying to get practical information from people who know the area. No book or description online can answer my question and forums like here are meant to help in that case. All I want to know is whether I am able to visit all those places within one day, and if not - which ones of them are the best choice, of course - a person giving answer would give personal opinion, I can live with that

Comment: I remember visiting about 3 - 4 of them over the years and it will be hard to get people who have visited all of them sufficient for a comparative judgement. Some are great in the spring, some you have to go in the autumn, some have adjacent tearooms and some have literary significance and  etc etc. And essentially the question boils down to an opinion poll where nobody's answer can be selected as absolutely correct over anybody else's answer.  Hence the comments that the question is off-topic.

Comment: Just saw this, and as someone who has visited all of those, some many times, I'd suggest you want a day for each one. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: Rory Alsop, thanks for the input, although I'm already after the trip :) I would say that a day per place would be a bit too much, especially having limited time (we wanted to see whole Scotland in 10 days :D) and there is not that much to see in those abbeys - they are beautiful of course, but usually there's no exhibition or anything to read, etc., so if you just want to walk across the grounds, take pictures, maybe climb the stairs to the tower (where possible), then 2-3 hours is enough. Out of those I've been to, only in Rosslyn Chapel there was some "lecture" and exhibition